# Se puede hacer que un link cargue automaticamente un onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quisiera consultar lo siguiente, me gustaria saber :

Este se trata de un proyecto offline las personas descargan el codigo y ejecutan en desde su pc directo en un navegador y todo es manejado desde el mismo `index.html`

Tengo un Javascript que contiene declaraciones de una botonera que son cargados en un `index.html` dentro de un `<div id="botonera"></div>`  los link de la botonera ejecutan un `onclick='funcion(#);'` que literalmente lo que hacen es cargar en un `<div id="contenido"></div>` el contenido que esta declarado en la funcion que llama el `onclick='funcion(#);'`

Eso tal cual como esta funciona, la persona debe hacer click para cargar el contenido de las botoneras, pero ahora **Mi duda**
Sera posible hacer que cuando un usuario pueda llamar por ejemplo a una web esta ejecute de forma automática el onclick requerido, tratare de graficar mi ejemplo:

Si se llama a `file:///home/documentos/ruta/index.html#contenido1` entonces se ejecute como que si se le hubiera dado click al boton que llama a la funcion `contenido1()`

o si se llama a la web `file:///home/documentos/ruta/index.html#ejercicios1` se ejecute la funcion `ejercicios(1)`

`file:///home/documentos/ruta/index.html#ejercicios2` se ejecute la funcion `ejercicios(2)`

**Mi codigo de la botonera es la siguiente**

```
function botonera() {

  var avl = a + v + l;

  botonera = "<nav class='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top' style='background-color: #c9deff;'>" +
    "<div class='container'>" +
    '<a onclick="bienvenida();" title="Cargar Inicio" class="navbar-brand" href="#Bienvenida">' + logoje + ' </a>' +
    '<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">' +
    '<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>' +
    '</button>' +
    '<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">' +
    '<ul class="navbar-nav">' +

    '<li class="nav-item">' +
    '<a onclick="bienvenida();" title="Cargar Inicio" class="nav-link active" href="#Bienvenida"><i class="fas fa-home fa-fw"></i> Inicio' +
    '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>' +
    '</a>' +
    '</li>' +


    '<li id="dropdown-secciones" class="nav-item dropdown">' +
    '<a title="Secciones" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece fa-fw"></i>  Secciones' +
    '</a>' +

    '<div id="dropdown-secci" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">' +

    "<a onclick='videos(1);' name='Videos_Seccion_1' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_1' class='dropdown-item'>01 Videos Bienvenida " + v + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(2);' name='Videos_Seccion_2' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_2' class='dropdown-item'>02 Videos Entorno de Aprendizaje " + v + w + z + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(3);' name='Videos_Seccion_3' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_3' class='dropdown-item'>03 Videos Introduccion Informal " + v + w + z + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(4);' name='Videos_Seccion_4' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_4' class='dropdown-item'>04 Videos Operadores y Expresiones " + v + w + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(5);' name='Videos_Seccion_5' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_5' class='dropdown-item'>05 Videos Controlando el flujo " + v + w + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(6);' name='Videos_Seccion_6' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_6' class='dropdown-item'>06 Videos Colecciones de datos " + v + w + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(7);' name='Videos_Seccion_7' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_7' class='dropdown-item'>07 Videos Entradas y salidas de datos " + v + w + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(8);' name='Videos_Seccion_8' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_8' class='dropdown-item'>08 Videos Programacion de funciones " + v + w + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(9);' name='Videos_Seccion_9' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_9' class='dropdown-item'>09 Videos Manejo de excepciones " + v + w + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(10);' name='Videos_Seccion_10' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_10' class='dropdown-item'>10 Videos Clases y objetos " + v + w + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(11);' name='Videos_Seccion_11' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_11' class='dropdown-item'>11 Videos Herencia " + v + w + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(12);' name='Videos_Seccion_12' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_12' class='dropdown-item'>12 Videos Metodos de las colecciones " + v + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(13);' name='Videos_Seccion_13' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_13' class='dropdown-item'>13 Videos Modulos y paquetes " + v + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(14);' name='Videos_Seccion_14' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_14' class='dropdown-item'>14 Videos Manejo de ficheros " + v + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(15);' name='Videos_Seccion_15' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_15' class='dropdown-item'>15 Videos Interfaces graficas con Tkinter " + v + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(16);' name='Videos_Seccion_16' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_16' class='dropdown-item'>16 Videos Bases de datos con SQLite " + v + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(17);' name='Videos_Seccion_17' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_17' class='dropdown-item'>17 Videos Funcionalidades avanzadas " + v + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(18);' name='Videos_Seccion_18' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_18' class='dropdown-item'>18 Videos Documentacion y pruebas " + v + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(19);' name='Videos_Seccion_19' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_19' class='dropdown-item'>19 Videos Distribucion " + w + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(20);' name='Videos_Seccion_20' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_20' class='dropdown-item'>20 Videos Anexos " + w + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick='videos(21);' name='Videos_Seccion_21' title='Videos' href='#Videos_Seccion_21' class='dropdown-item'>21 Videos Bonus " + w + " </a>" +
    "<a onclick = 'glosario();' title = 'Glosario de Terminos' name = 'Glosario de Terminos' href='#glosario' class='dropdown-item'>Glosario de Terminos <span class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-book' aria-hidden = 'true'> </span> " + i + " </a>" +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>' +

    '<li>' +
    "<a href = '#extra' title = 'Ver Extensiones Instaladas' name = 'Extensiones' onclick = 'extra();' class='nav-link'> Extensiones  " + e + " </a>" +
    '</li>' +

    '<li>' +
    "<a href = '#Creditos' onclick = 'creditos();' title = 'Creditos' name = 'Creditos' class='nav-link'>Creditos " + r + " </a>" +
    '</li>' +

    '</ul>' +
    '</div>' +
    "</div></nav>";

  bienvenida();
  footer_site();

  document.getElementById('botonera').innerHTML = botonera, document.getElementById('foot').innerHTML = foot, document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML = contenido;
  mensextra();

  $('li a').click(function(e) {
     //e.preventDefault();
     $('a').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');

  });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener la *url* de la página con `window.location.href` y manejarla a tu antojo. Por ejemplo:

```
var funcName = window.location.href.split('#')[1];

if (funcName != undefined) {

    eval(funcName + '()');

}
```

Tendrías que complicar un poco el ejemplo para manejar los parámetros que recibe la función que quieres ejecutar.

Un saludo!